# Bootstrap modal, django for loop and model | same value displaying error Fixed

Tags: html, django, for-loop, bootstrap-modal

Would you like the modal to display corresponding loop values or messages?

When I tried to print the order message in modals, it showed the same message for every order,  which led me to realize that every time we call the same modal ID, it shows the same message for every order,

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain how I fixed it here

1. In button ( for opening modal )

   ```
      data-target="#exampleModal"

       to

       data-target="#exampleModal{{ forloop.counter }}"
   ```
2. in modal

   ```
   id="exampleModal"

    to 

   id="exampleModal{{ forloop.counter }}"
   ```

Example :

```
             <tbody>
              {% for Order in orders %}
              <tr>
            
                <td style="width:120px;">{{Order.order_date}}</td>
                <td>{{Order.customer}}</td>
                <td>{{Order.customer.customer_phone}}</td>
                <td>{{Order.total_items}}</td>
                <td>{{Order.total_amount}}</td>
              
                <td>
                    {% comment %} <div class="hovertext" data-hover="{{Order.order_message}}">{{Order.order_message|truncatechars:20}}</div> {% endcomment %}
                    {% comment %} view order button and while clicking this buttonn show message in pop up {% endcomment %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{ forloop.counter }}">
                        View Order
                      </button>
                      
                      <!-- Modal -->
                      <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Order Message</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" style="color:dark;">
                              {% comment %} oder make in formated way {% endcomment %}
                              {{Order.order_message}}
                            </div>  
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                  </td>
              </tr>
              
              {% endfor %}
```